# Getting error message Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js) when running npm serve

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, sass-loader

I'm working on a Vue/Vuetify project for quite some time now. It all worked fine until yesterday. I had problems with using the `<v-simple-table>` vuetify component, so I decided to run npm install and re-install vuetify: bad idea.

The problem is that I get the following error multiple times when running `npm run serve`:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'indentedSyntax'. These properties are valid:
   object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }
    at validate (C:\Users\Jeroen\Documents\favourite_xi\node_modules\sass-loader\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:49:11)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\Jeroen\Documents\favourite_xi\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:36:28)

 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/VCalendar/mixins/calendar-with-events.sass 4:14-225 14:3-18:5 15:22-233
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VCalendar/mixins/calendar-with-events.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VCalendar/VCalendar.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VCalendar/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.178.115:8080/sockjs-node ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

My main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  theme: {
    "primary": "#FFCA28",
    "secondary": "#1976D2",
    "accent": "#82B1FF",
    "error": "#FF5252",
    "info": "#2196F3",
    "success": "#4CAF50",
    "warning": "#FB8C00"
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

I've already looked at multiple posts and they all advise to run `npm rebuild node-sass` (both regularly as in admin-mode), delete the node-modules folder, re-install sass-loader, but nothing worked so far.

Is there something wrong in my main.js maybe?

Thanks in advance! Let me know if I need to post more of my code or additional information.

Edit: added package.json

```
{
  "name": "favourite_xi",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.22",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.7",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-cool-select": "^2.10.2",
    "vue-flip": "^0.3.0",
    "vue-responsive-text": "^0.1.4",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.3",
    "vuetify": "^2.0.16",
    "vuex": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.10.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.8.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.8.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.8.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "webpack": "^4.39.3"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "@vue/standard"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

Comment: So, you `npm install` runs through after deleting the `node_modules`?

Comment: Did you update anything in the package.json? Seems like there is an incompatibility between your node modules. See here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4513 Updating `vue-cli` should probably resolve it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Updating vue-cli didn't help. `npm install` did run after deleting my node-modules, but no luck either

Comment: Just checked out an older commit. This doesn't work anymore either...

Comment: Tried the following: deleted node modules and package-lock.json. Updated vue cli. Ran `npm i`. Replaced package.json with the one from an older (working) commit. Same error

Comment: encountering the same issue right now but where you able to solve this ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This could be result of upgrading `sass-loader` from v7.x to v8.x

As stated in [release notes](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/releases/tag/v8.0.0), they'v made significant changes to configuration

Check your `vue.config.js` - if you find something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        ....some options here...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

change it to:

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        sassOptions: {
          ....some options here...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if it's of any use but my `npm run build` errors at the color codes in theme. When I comment out the color code lines it builds without error:

```
    Vue.use(Vuetify, {
      theme: {
        "primary": "#FFCA28",
        "secondary": "#1976D2",
        "accent": "#82B1FF",
        "error": "#FF5252",
        "info": "#2196F3",
        "success": "#4CAF50",
        "warning": "#FB8C00"
      }
    })
```