# _plugins_vuetify__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.default is not a constructor

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

[image: here is the new error]I had an issue upon installing vuetify to my project, I followed some solutions in some questions but still I had an issue.

Here is my vuetify.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const opts = {}

export default new Vuetify(opts)
```

App.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from '../plugins/vuetify';
Vue.use(Vuetify);

new Vue ({
    router,
    vuetify : new Vuetify(),
    render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');


const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin')
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');

  var webpackConfig = {
    plugins: [
        new VuetifyLoaderPlugin(),
        new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
      ],
  }

mix.webpackConfig( webpackConfig );

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

[image: Here is the picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but you're trying `new` up `Vuetify` when you should just be passing it in like this:

```
new Vue ({
    router,
    vuetify: Vuetify, // <-- simply set it like this
    render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

Comment: Hi @maxshuty, when I copied your solution but I still have an error, please see the picture at the top of the page

Comment: @enriquetanada that seems unrelated to this as it seems that this has resolved the Vuetify issues at least. Have a look at this answer for how to fix that issue you're seeing now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58842923/4826740